# How to location a specific row to the top of a NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I want to location a row to the top of a NSOutlineView. What I find is `scrollRowToVisible:`.But it only can location the row to the bottom of the NSOutlineView.

My OutlineView'scrollView is using autolayout and the row height is variable.So I don't want to get the scrollView'height by its constraints then do some calculate and use `scrollRowToVisible:` by plus the calculate'result.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer my own question:

```
NSRect rect=[_tableView rectOfRow:row];
[_tableView.enclosingScrollView.documentView scrollPoint:rect.origin];
[_tableView.enclosingScrollView displayIfNeeded];
```